# cpp vector<vector<int> > to void* and back

Tags: c++, vector, casting, extern, void-pointers

I have a method that looks like that:

```
vector<vector<int> > doSomething(vector<vector<int> > vec);
```

I need to externalize this method as part of an API, so I use extern "C".
For this purpose, I thought of changing the function to:

```
void* doSomething(void* vec);
```

How do I casting from void* to vector<vector >  and  from vector<vector > to void* ?

I tried the following:

```
vector<<vector<int> >  newVec =  reinterpret_cast< vector <vector<int> >  >(vec);
```

and

```
return (void*)newVec;
```

but I got the following errors:

> error: invalid cast from type 'void*' to type 'std::vectorstd::vector<int >'
> vector <vector >  newVec =  reinterpret_cast< vector <vector
>
> > > (vec);
>
> invalid cast from type 'std::vectorstd::vector<int >' to type 'void*'
> return (void*) newVec;

Comment: Please, don't speak vaguely about "errors", include the **exact error text** in your question.

Comment: A side note: Since C++11, you can directly use `vector<vector<int>>`, no need to have a space between the two closing angle bracket. This will make your code much more readable.

Comment: You cannot cast `std::vector<SomeType>` to/from `void*` but you can with `std::vector<SomeType>*`.

Comment: `vector<<vector<int>>& newVec = *reinterpret_cast<vector<vector<int>>*>(vec);`

Comment: How does this API work? How are the two sides supposed to be using it? If you want to work with a `std::vector` shared across the API, then both sides need to know about it anyway and there is no point in making it `extern "C"`. Or do you only want to pass the object through a C API without touching the contents? Then a casting the vector pointer from/to `void*` is fine to get through that C API, but you need to take care of lifetime management manually.

Comment: There are two issues here: One is purely technical, about the error you get and how to solve it. For that, your question lacks a [mcve]. The other is the higher-level design of the API, for which your question lacks infos how that API is supposed to work. Tackle the second question first, because technically good implementation of a bad idea is still a bad idea.

Comment: You cannot pass anything other than pointers (and perhaps trivailly copyable values with a size of at most `sizeof(void*)` ) via `void*`. This could be used for passing any information though C style functions, if you're using the classic function pointer + context, see https://godbolt.org/z/szr1Pq6dn ; You may simply want to create wrapper types though that are only forward declared in your C api, if you're implementing a C wrapper for C++ code, e.g. publi header: `struct IntVectorVectorWrapper;`, internal header: `struct IntVectorVectorWrapper { std::vector<std::vector<int>>& m_ref; };`